# Words jumped in output using hebrew

Tags: hebrew

My codes are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hebrew,russian,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item
  \textbf{Form}: WG\\
  \textbf{Contributor}: Hila Gendler Shalev, Tel-Aviv University\\
  \textbf{Citation}: 
  Gendler-Shalev, H. (2005). 
  \selectlanguage{hebrew}התאמת שאלון  הורים \selectlanguage{english} 
  HCDI-WG 
  \selectlanguage{hebrew}לעברית\selectlanguage{english} 
    [The adaptation of HCDI-WG parent questionnaire to Hebrew] [Master's Thesis, Tel Aviv University, Tev Aviv, Israel].
\end{itemize}
    
    \end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

As per my code, the text "HCDI-WG" should come after the hebrew characters, but it comes before that. Please suggest what I did wrong...

Note that I'm using MikTeX 2.9 (LaTeX->dvips->ps2pdf) and Windows7...

Comment: Don't use `\selectlanguage` in the middle of a paragraph. Use `\foreignlanguage` instead. In this case, try nesting a `\foreignlanguage` for English inside a `\foreignlanguage` for Hebrew, but I couldn't test it because it doesn't work in TeXLive (no fonts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixing L-R and R-L languages creates a lot of potentially ambiguous situations. Pierre MacKay's article on TeX-XeT from way back when addressed some of these. What's happening is that it's treating the HCDI-WG (and the later English text) as being part of the surrounding Hebrew (so L-R embedded in R-L) rather than the Hebrew being embedded in the surrounding English. I don't have everything installed to be able to test this (or even run your example—I'm getting a missing font error that I'm too lazy to resolve), but you should be able to enclose your Hebrew in `\R{...}` to get your desired result.

Edited to include following (untested) MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hebrew,russian,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item
  \textbf{Form}: WG\\
  \textbf{Contributor}: Hila Gendler Shalev, Tel-Aviv University\\
  \textbf{Citation}: 
  Gendler-Shalev, H. (2005). 
  \R{התאמת שאלון  הורים} 
  HCDI-WG 
  \R{לעברית} 
    [The adaptation of HCDI-WG parent questionnaire to Hebrew] [Master's Thesis, Tel Aviv University, Tev Aviv, Israel].
\end{itemize}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\documentclass{book}\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}\usepackage[hebrew,russian,english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item
\begin{otherlanguage}{hebrew}התאמת שאלון  הורים\end{otherlanguage} \selectlanguage{english} 
  HCDI-WG 
  \selectlanguage{hebrew}לעברית\selectlanguage{english} 
    [The adaptation of HCDI-WG parent questionnaire to Hebrew] [Master's Thesis, Tel Aviv University, Tev Aviv, Israel].
\end{itemize}
 \end{document}` not working...

Comment: I think you might be seeing an old version of the post. I was suggesting writing something like `\R{התאמת שאלון  הורים}` anywhere you have Hebrew, which should make it clear to TeX that it's Hebrew embedded in English and not the other way around

Comment: You shouldn't need to write `\selectlanguage{hebrew}` at all.

Comment: Sorry sir, Can you provide a `MWE` for your suggestion? As I tried, but couldn't able to succeed...

Comment: I created a MWE above. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Much thanks sir, will check and get back to you...

Comment: It's working like a champ...Thanks for your kind support...